# symfony 2 notification or alert (for all user)

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

Hi everyone Im working on a symfony2 project,and my next step is to create a simple notification system, 
when someone add insert a row in an entity, the others must be notified in the moment,
I wonder if I create a bloc of jquery code that get the date of the last created element and then do the rest work (show a notification ) I dont think is a good idea, or if there is a nice and a simple method to follow to create a notification system,
plz any idea could be helpful.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What you need is long polling.

Comment: could you give me more explanation plz ?

Comment: http://knpbundles.com/varspool/WebsocketBundle

Answer (score 0):

You shoul implement something like this:

1. Client send an ajax request with timestamp of last modification (first time sends 0)
2. Server compares timestamp of client to timestamp, to retrieve all messages with bigger timestamp than the one sent by user
3. If there are newer messages, return them immediately to the client, with the timestamp of the latest one On other hand, if there are no new messages, enter into a 2 minutes busy-wait loop, checking every 1-3 seconds (randomly) whether there are new messages.
4. When client receive servers answer, browser updates view and immediately sends a new ajax request.

Comment: To explain my case, I have an entity called purchaseRequest, when a new element is created and added to the database, the master should be notified to validate id!!!

Comment: What is the master? a client(browser)?

Comment: which has the previledge of validation